# How Can I Solve ValueError dtype Without Using An Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, valueerror

I am working on a program that is supposed to update employees salaries by %5 and %10 based on age:

```
import csv
infile = open('employee.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(infile)

rows = []
for row in csvreader:
  rows.append(row)

for i in rows:
  if(int(i[2]) < 40):      #LINE CAUSING A PROBLEM
    i[3] = round((1.05 * float(i[3])) , 2)
  else:
    i[3] = round((1.10 * float(i[3])) , 2)

print('\n\nList after updation:')
#loop print the data on the compile
for row in rows:
  print(row)

#open file and write the updated data
with open('employeeUpdate.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
---> 23   if(int(i[2]) < 40):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'age'
```

Data Sample:

```
ID   employee name   age   salary
1    Sara Wales      33    60994
2    John Smith      42    78399
3    Michael Ousley  22    58000
4    Rami Elliot     50    88382
```

I double-checked the data type and it was an integer-->`('age', dtype('int64'))`

I tried `with open ('employee.csv', r) as infile` and changing the problem line to `if int(float(i[2]) < 40):` but they both did not work.
It said cannot convert string to float. I don't know why it is reading the integer as a string.

But when I added an exception like this:

```
for i in rows:
  try:
    if (int(i[2]) < 40):
        i[3] = round((1.05 * int(i[3])) , 2)
    else:
        i[3] = round((1.10 * int(i[3])) , 2)
  except ValueError:
        print("")
```

It worked, so my question is why did it only work with the exception!, and is there a way I can have it done without the exception?

Comment: from the error looks like you are getting string at i[2], can you also post the sample input

Comment: @RoboC: 
Is there any reason you are not considering using pandas  ? That would make this so much easier and can you please post a small sample

Comment: please share some info about employee.csv , it's probably some info that it's being skipped by try/except (maybe you have headers or something)

Comment: @Hackaholic I added the sample

Comment: @UGuntupalli No specific reason for not using pandas, i just did it this way. I added a sample of the csv file

Comment: @fatemehyadollahzadeh I provided a sample of the file

Comment: @UGuntupalli making dataframe in memory is costly operation, i dont recommend pandas until one has to to multiple operations, may be in hundreds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `csv.reader()` continuously reads a stream until EOF, it doesn't have a concept of a header row. For the first iteration of `rows`, `i` would always be the string header row. And you're trying to convert the text "age" into int which would Python to error.

Your try-except works because it simply masks the error raised from the first row and prints a blank line instead.

To  fix it, simply skip a line from the file to not include the header row, or skip the first iteration when doing the int conversion.

```
with open('employee.csv') as infile:
    infile.readline()
    csvreader = csv.reader(infile)
    # do stuff with csvreader
```

When handling large datasets and doing complicated data manipulations, consider using the pandas library. The issue described here and dtype conversions would automatically be handled by pandas.